# One table references an unknown number of other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm creating a cataloguing application with a SQL backend. The user will be able to create their own collections. When a user creates a collection, a new SQL table is created with attributes that have been chosen by the user. For exampe, the user could create a collections called "Books" with the attributes "Author" and "Title". The program would then create a table called "Books" with the attributes "Author" and "Title".

I have a table called collections in which the name of each collection is stored. I then have a table for each collection created by the the user. I essentially want the single collections table to reference multiple tables. The reason my question is different to those I've found on the Internet is that I don't know how many tables I will need to reference as each table is created by the user. Also, I can't put all the items in the same table as each table has different attributes.

This is the entity-relationship diagram I have so far, there can b any amount of UserCreatedTables

[image]

How would I go about referencing an unknown number of tables from one table?

Comment: This is a poor design. Dynamic information should be in table contents, not table names.

Comment: EAV pattern is more suitable.